# Margin and Padding makes image bigger

Tags: html, css, image

I want to push the logo.png so it is about a third of the way across the page. When I create a large padding or margin, the image gets larger despite the other code limiting the image size.

```
.header {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}

.class {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  margin-left: 300px;
}


<body>
<div class="header">
<table>
  <tr><td><img src="Logo.png" class="class"></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to push the image further horizontal while keeping the image size the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following: With `margin-left` on the `img` tag which is inside of the `td` you change the width of the `td` to the value of `margin-left` (it just adapts the size of it's children). To keep proportions the image scales up.
Since table cells does **not** respect `width` and will be collapsed based on the `width` of the entire `table`, you have to specify the `width` of `table` to set a limitation of `width` or maybe switch to `<div>` elements where you have full flexibility.

The header `width` / `height` does not limit the width/height of your `table`, because – as I said – it's adapt it's children widths / heights. So the inner element (the table) is bigger, so it overflows his parent.